# Regular expression for name field in javascript validation

Tags: javascript

i need a regular expression in javascript validation.
Regular expression for name field that will accept alphabets and only space character between words and total characters in the field should be in between 2 and 30. i.e., the field should accept min 2 chars and max of 30 chars

Comment: i need a regular expression for the name field in javascript.

Comment: That's still not a question. And you should not be doing this. Read http://www.kalzumeus.com/2010/06/17/falsehoods-programmers-believe-about-names/

Comment: Thank you Tim Pietzcker.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

```
function validate(id) {
    var regex = /^[a-zA-Z ]{2,30}$/;
    var ctrl =  document.getElemetnById(id);
    return regex.test(ctrl.value);
}
```

Comment: you could replace your conditional statement with `return test(ctrl.value);`

Comment: I believe you meant: `return regex.test(ctrl.value)`

Comment: what about diacritic characters? english is not the only language on earth

Comment: <script type="text/javascript">
        function isAlfa(evt) {
            evt = (evt) ? evt : window.event;
            var charCode = (evt.which) ? evt.which : evt.keyCode;
            if (charCode > 32 && (charCode < 65 || charCode > 90) && (charCode < 97 || charCode > 122)) {
                return false;
            }
            return true;
        }
 function toTitleCase(str) {
            return str.replace(/\w\S*/g, function (txt) {
                return txt.charAt(0).toUpperCase() + txt.substr(1).toLowerCase();
            });
        }


    </script>

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
/^([a-zA-Z ]){2,30}$/
```

Answer (score -1):

your solution would be.

```
 /^[a-zA-Z ]{2,30}$/;
```

Note: just add a space within the brackets. other whitespace characters like -tab, form feed, and line feed ,will not match.